# Display category list without link wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to list category names. `wp_list_categories()` returns a list of the categories but the problem is that it automatically wraps the names with links. I do not need the links.

It is possible to disable the links by JavaScript? But then I would have to fire some JS event.

I need to retrieve the category list without the automatic anchor tags, any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this using the wordpress function [get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/),
this should work :

**PHP**

```
 <ul>
  <?php
  foreach (get_categories() as $category){
    echo "<li>";
    echo $category->name;
    echo "</li>";
  } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12):

This works well, with less code:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Comment: This will only display the first category, not all of them.

Comment: Your code will list the categories of the current post; I'm not sure that's what the question was asking for. They want to list all available categories.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a list of all existing categories but don't like how `wp_list_categories()` formats the result. Try to use [get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) instead, it just retrieves a list of category objects.

You can combine it with [wp_list_pluck()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/), which plucks a certain field out of each object (here the `name` key). You'll get an array containing only this key, and you'll be able to display your list with `implode()`.

For example:

```
echo implode( ', ', wp_list_pluck( get_categories(), 'name' ) );
```